# Updating Issues with MySQL and Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, odbc

So this is a problem which started happening a day ago.

I have an Access database file which stores a form for creating jobs, updating job sector, and deleting it from the MySQL table.

There are two tables that are used for this form: a local one stored in Access called "Job Route" and another through MYSQL ODBC Driver, ANSI 5.3 version called "To Do". The local table stores user-submitted data containing information on all job areas and state, while the MYSQL table only shows one job area at a time.

When a new entry is created, the text box details from the Access form are being stored onto both tables. Where each job contains up to 4 different sectors (e.g. [start date], [area1], [person in charge 1], [description1], ... [area4], [person in charge 4], [description4]). Whenever the data is being updated to its next state, in the local table only the job counter field is incremented, while every field in the MYSQL table called "To Do" is updated to its next state fields.

Connection to the server is good, and everything was running fine until an issue popped up in the updating function.

Basically how that function works is that on a listbox control, all current job data is being queried from the "To Do" table. The user selects an entry, and hits a button which loads the next sector information data from "Job Route", onto various textbox controls. The user can change those textbox inputs if they want - the only thing that is changed when the function runs is the "To Do". The information in "Job Route" remains the same. When the user hits the update button, the next sector field data is updated to "To Do", while only a counter in "Job Route" is being incremented to signify the current sector.

My problem is this. For the most part almost everything is running fine, but for one of the fields in "To Do" table does not update with the values it should from the textbox. So for instance if the textbox control was set to "Wyntile", the field name should be set to that, but for some reason a different value shows up instead, example="Apples". Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub moveJob2_Click()

'get the job number
JobNum = Text31

CurrArea = DLookup("[Area]", "[To_Do]", "[Job_Number] =""" & JobNum & """")
area1 = DLookup("[Area1]", "[Job Route]", "[Job Number] =""" & JobNum & """")
area2 = DLookup("[Area2]", "[Job Route]", "[Job Number] =""" & JobNum & """")
area3 = DLookup("[Area3]", "[Job Route]", "[Job Number] =""" & JobNum & """")
area4 = DLookup("[Area4]", "[Job Route]", "[Job Number] =""" & JobNum & """")

'get what the current area is
Current = DLookup("[Current]", "[Job Route]", "[Job Number] =""" & JobNum & """")

'if the current area is the first area then check to make sure there is a second
'if so, then set the new area to it
If Current = 1 Then
    If area2 = "---" Then
        MsgBox area1 + " was the last area in the route. The job cannot be moved."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    newArea = area2
ElseIf Current = 2 Then
    If area3 = "---" Then
        MsgBox area2 + " was the last area in the route. The job cannot be moved."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    newArea = area3
ElseIf Current = 3 Then
    If area4 = "---" Then
        MsgBox area3 + " was the last area in the route. The job cannot be moved."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    newArea = area4
Else
    MsgBox area4 + " was the last area in the route. The job cannot be moved."
    Exit Sub
End If

'set up link to both the To_Do and Job Route tables
Dim dbJobNumbers As DAO.Database
Dim rstJob As DAO.Recordset
Dim jobRoute As DAO.Recordset

Set dbJobNumbers = CurrentDb
Set rstJob = dbJobNumbers.OpenRecordset("To_Do")
Set jobRoute = dbJobNumbers.OpenRecordset("Job Route")

' >> Edit the job in the To_Do table
****' ERROR: Out of all these, only [Person_In_Charge] is being set to something
****' completely different from Text33, which wasn't changed by the user.

rstJob.FindFirst "[Job_Number]=""" + Text31 + """"
rstJob.Edit
rstJob("[Area]").Value = newArea
rstJob("[Person_In_Charge]").Value = Text33  
rstJob("[Equipment]").Value = Text37
rstJob("[Description]").Value = Text35
rstJob.Update

'update the current area for the Job Route
jobRoute.FindFirst "[Job Number]=""" + Text31 + """"
jobRoute.Edit
jobRoute("[Current]").Value = CInt(Current) + 1
jobRoute.Update

'success message
MsgBox Text31 + " has been moved from " + CurrArea + " to " + newArea + "."

'requery the listboxes
Dim selectParas As String
selectParas = "SELECT [a].[Job_Number] as [Job Number], [a].[Description], [a].[Person_In_Charge] as [Person in Charge], [a].[Area] " & _
              " FROM [To_Do] As [a];"

listRemoveJobs.RowSource = selectParas
listRemoveJobs.Requery
listChangeJobArea.RowSource = selectParas
listChangeJobArea.Requery

End Sub
```

The function has been running fine, and even now when I test it again it runs as programmed. Though today I recieved the "ODBC Insert on 'To Do' has failed" error, but that's for a different function. So I was thinking that something is wrong in the ODBC connection/MySQL table, but when I checked the table in phpmyadmin for the most part that table follows a similar format of other mysql tables used in Access.

Also to note, the person who had told me this issue runs on an old Windows XP version, where once before on that computer there were known issues of the defined OBDC ANSI 5.3 Driver instance completely disappearing from Access' Data Source list before. (The driver is still installed on Windows). That time, apparently the driver instance later re-appeared again magically in the D.S. list when that computer was restarted. ... I know this is rather long, but I can't seem to find the cause of why this updating error in Access is happening. Is there a known issue of ODBC having stability issues in connection? Why is the value changed to something completely different on update? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Does *Apples* have anything to do with your application or date? Think carefully. It cannot be just random.

Comment: That's just an example, but the random value set is a name used in other job entries. But that name value doesn't exist in the specific "Job Route" entry anywhere. (person_in_chargeN) And since you mentioned it, no matter the job number they all get set to the same person's name for some reason so... it's definitely not random. The textbox values do get populated correctly from the local table.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no reproducible example to help with your specific situation, consider running pure SQL `UPDATE` queries with binded parameters. Your *area* conditional logic can be rewritten into nested `IIF` expression. Possibly, this will simplify your problem and streamline your needs without `DLookup` or multiple recordset updates. Also, your re-assignment to `RowSource` is not necessary. Below utilizes parameterization, a best practice when running SQL in application layer:

**SQL** *(save both below as Access queries)*

1. **mySavedJoinUpdateQuery**

   ```
   PARAMETERS Text33Param Text(255), Text35Param Text(255)
              Text37Param Text(255), JobNumberParam Text(255);
   UPDATE [To_Do] d
   INNER JOIN [Job Route] r
   ON d.Job_Number = r.Job_Number

   SET [Area] = IIF([Current] = 1 AND [Area2] != '---', [Area2], 
                    IIF([Current] = 2 AND [Area3] != '---', [Area3], 
                        IIF([Current] = 3 AND [Area4] != '---', [Area4], [Area1)
                    )
                ),
       [Person_In_Charge] = Text33Param,
       [Equipment] = Text37Param,
       [Description] = Text35Param

   WHERE r.[Job Number] = JobNumberParam;
   ```
2. **mySavedSimpleUpdateQuery**

   ```
   PARAMETERS JobNumberParam Text(255);
   UPDATE [Job Route] r
   SET r.[Current] = r.[Current] + 1
   WHERE r.[Job Number] = JobNumberParam;
   ```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub moveJob2_Click()
   Dim qdef As QueryDef
   Dim selectParas As String

   ' UPDATE JOIN QUERY
   Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedJoinUpdateQuery")

   qdef!JobNumberParam = Text31
   qdef!Text33Param = Text33
   qdef!Text35Param = Text35
   qdef!Text37Param = Text37

   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError 
   Set qdef = Nothing

   ' UPDATE SIMPLE QUERY
   Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedSimpleUpdateQuery")

   qdef!JobNumberParam = Text31   
   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError 
   Set qdef = Nothing

   ' REQUERY LIST BOXES
   listRemoveJobs.Requery
   listChangeJobArea.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out! Hopefully it becomes the case where using outdated/slow VBA mechanics was the reason why different values were being set on update. I knew DAO is not really recommended use these days, but I hope that was causing the random update error. This error happens rarely so unless I see the error happening myself I can't trace it and the reason.